# How do I decide a value for MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT?

Tags: magento2, performance, indexing, indexer

Can anyone suggest to me how to decide a value for `MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT`?

I am managing a website that has 5 websites, 10 stores, 6 customer groups. I know adding this environment variable can increase indexer performance but I am not able to decide what should be the correct value for the website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how many threads you have in your server, to check if you can run this command below.

```
nproc
```

You will see something like this:

[image: MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT]

Then you can test as I did below, you will see that you can run the reindex process much faster allowing it to run with more threads allocated to it.

```
MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=$(nproc) php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

[image: Magento 2 MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT]

Then you can modify your file `env.php` to add it.

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORGIN',
'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
'MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT' => '40',
'session' => [
    'save' => 'memcache',
    'save_path' => 'tcp://memcache:11211'
],
```